# How to store many items of data per SESSION?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

## I have a query called "rsUserRights" which returns User Rights like such:

```
UserID | Entity | Right
-----------------------
1        Note     Create
1        Note     Edit
1        Note     Delete
```

This means that UserID '1' can create, edit, or delete a Note object.

All I want to do this store these permissions in a SESSION array so that the web applications know all the time what rights the logged in User has. So when a User is looking at a Note object in my applciation, the correct option to Create, Edit, or Delete will be available depending on what rights this User has.

The application needs to know what object the user has a right to, and then what is that right. Some users may not have rights expect read-only. How do I store this Entity-Right key-value pair in a ColdFusion structure?

All I have managed to do so far is this:

```
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights = StructNew()>
<cfloop query="rsUserRights">
  <cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights.#rsUserRights.Entity#>
  <cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights.#rsUserRights.Entity#.#rsUserRights.Right#>
</cfloop>
```

Would the above work? Then using structkeyexits to find value-pairs? The problem I can see is that I could end up with a shed load of SESSION variables because the user may have hundreds of rights to hundreds of entities/objects. It will therefore create hundreds of SESSION variables and crash my server?

---

**FIRST ATTEMPT SOLUTION**

```
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights = StructNew()>
  <cfloop query="rsUserRights">
    <cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights[rsUserRights.Entity][rsUserRights.Right] = StructNew()>
  </cfloop>
```

Then in my CFM pages I test for the existence of SESSION.Auth.UserRights.Note AND SESSION.UserRights.Note.Create for example

Is this ok??

Comment: Have you actually tried using that code? If not, why not? If so, what exactly is not working as you expected?

Comment: I havent tried it yet. I just thought it was too basic to be robust and scalable. Im worried about it causing server to run out of memory in the future if the user rights table grows massively which i think it will

Comment: Given your concern about too many rights per user, look into roles.  It might simplify things as well as taking less RAM.

Comment: I have added Roles... but Roles will have their rights change whenever an administrator feels like it. They may suddenly remove the right to Create a Note from the Manager role for example. Therefore my web application needs to be concerned with what rights a user has rather what Role he has. Do you agree?

Comment: I disagree big time.  If someone authorized to make a decision does so, your application should ensure that decision is implemented.

Comment: You could implement role updates by having an application scoped variable (appropriately locked on update by an admin) set to a date/time, tickcount, integer, etc and then on each page request just check to see if SESSION.rolesUpdated neq Application.rolesUpdated.  If it's different recheck the roles.  Alternatively have role updates by the admin update an Application scoped variable for the rights and just check that.  <cfif Application.roles[User.currentRole].Note.Edit>

Comment: Whoa my head is going mushy. I only just figured out that Roles have Rights, hence the Rights that a Role has can change often depending on what senior management decide. I can't see how I can hard-code Role based permissions into the application when one day a Role has all rights and the next day no rights! I'm talking about rights all the way down to web form field level. Hence almost every HTML element is wrapped in a cfif condition. Am I going the wrong way about it all?

Comment: Stick to simple concepts.  Management can decide who can do what.  Your application simply has to ensure those decisions are implemented.  The details depend on the situation.  However, managing a few roles is easier than mangaging a lot of people.

Comment: Absolutely.... I'm not managing individual users in my application. All I am doing is when a CFM page loads up that includes a Note object for example, it is wrapped in a CFIF statement to check the user rights stored in the SESSION structure. If the user rights meet certain conditions, then the appropriate options will be available to that user e.g. Create, Edit, or Delete. I can't think of any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about how much memory this will take, then rather than loading lots of falses into your structure, only load when true.

```
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights = {}>
<cfloop query="rsUserRights">
   <cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights[Entity] ={}>

   <cfif Right EQ 1>
      <cfif SESSION.Auth.UserRights[Entity][Right] = true>
   </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Then all of your tests are for existence.

Comment: if you're concerned about memory use `true` or `false` so it's stored as a boolean rather than an int.

Comment: Good point.  You could also trim it even further and do some bit shifting to use a single numeric value.  e.g. cfset ... item XOR state

Comment: You should write that up as a separate answer

Answer (score 2):

That absolutely can work. Personally I would create a structure that contains the rights already defaulted to false and then on login update to true for those that match.

The reason being that you can then just check the perms instead of having to also check existence, etc. note that you should be doing a cflock but I'll leave that out of this example.

```
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights = {}>
<cfloop index="AuthRight" list="Note,User,Documents,Application,SomethingElse">
  <cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights[AuthRight]={Create=false,Edit=false,Delete=false}>
</cfloop>

<cfloop query="rsUserRights">
  <cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights[rsUserRights.Entity][rsUserRights.Right]=true>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the approach that unix web server / CHMOD permissions have. They use a single integer to denote what actions are possible for a given user.

```
http://www.zzee.com/solutions/unix-permissions.shtml
```

You could adapt your numbering to match the particular possible actions your app has - for example you might have 1 = add only, 2 = add & edit only, 3 = full add, edit & delete. Then for a user you'd just have a single digit entry for each type of object in your app. Your code might look like:

```
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights = structNew()>
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights.Note = 3>
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights.User = 1>
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights.Image = 2>
```

Checking if a user has the right permissions then involves some simple logic - depending on what actions you've got and how you've organised your numbering. Something like this:

```
<cfif SESSION.Auth.UserRights.Image GT 2>…
<cfif SESSION.Auth.UserRights.Note EQ 1>
```

If you're REALLY worried about space (and I wouldn't be) then you could just store those integers in a single list / array, and check for the integer in a particular position - but that might be tricky to keep track of as your app evolves.

```
<cfset SESSION.Auth.UserRights = "3,1,2,3">
<cfdump var="#listToArray(SESSION.Auth.UserRights)#">
<cfoutput>#listToArray(SESSION.Auth.UserRights)[1]#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: In my solution, I just test for existence. So if SESSION.Auth.UserRights.Note.Edit exists, then it means the User can Edit any Note objects. If the Edit key is not there in the structure, then it means they don't have this right. It prevents me from storing any values as such.... what do you think?

Comment: Any of the solutions on the page should work ok I think - I just figured you were worried about lots of SESSION vars mounting up so tried to think of the most efficient way they could be stored. You could just store a list / array of items to represent what actions are allowed - 'NoteEdit, NoteAdd' etc. Then when you want to do an action search the list? There's loads of ways to structure what you want to do, just a matter of personal preference I think.